# getting an Undefined index: id in submitting a form

Tags: php, api, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I got this error yesterday and I thought I fixed it.  I am submitting an update form.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

 @section('content')
  <form action="{{url('/student/update')}}" method="POST" role="form">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

{{method_field('PUT')}}
<legend>Create a Student</legend>
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="{{$student->id}}">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$student->name }}"required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Address</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{{$student->address }}" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{$student->phone }}" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Career</label>
  <select name="career" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option>Select a Career</option>
    <option value="math"{{$student->career == 'math' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Math</option>
    <option value="physics"{{$student->career == 'physics' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Physics</option>
    <option value="engineering"{{$student->career == '' ? 'engineering' : ''}}>Engineering</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Student</button>
</form>

@endsection
```

The error says that it relates to my ClientController on line 82.

```
protected function updateOneStudent($parameters)
{

  $studentId = $parameters['id'];
  return $this-
 >performPutRequest("https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students/{$studentId}", 
 $parameters);
    }
```

It was the same function that was giving me the problem yesterday.  The problem was that I was not calling a function.  The performPutRequest function is like this.

```
protected function performPutRequest($url, $parameters = [])
{
  $contents = $this->performAuthorizeRequest('PUT', $url, $parameters);

  $decodedContents = json_decode($contents);

  return $decodedContents->data;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `$studentId = $parameters['id'];` should be `$studentId = $parameters->id;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.

Comment: show us where you're calling `updateOneStudent()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks beginner for point me in the right direction.  I had the code below.

```
protected function updateOneStudent($parameters)
{

  $studentId = $parameters['id';
  return $this->performPutRequest("https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students/{$studentId}", $parameters);

}
```

I missed a bracket from the id.  So it should look like this

```
protected function updateOneStudent($parameters)
{

  $studentId = $parameters['id'];
  return $this->performPutRequest("https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students/{$studentId}", $parameters);

}
```